# exe generated by py2exe and pyinstaller not working

Tags: python, pyinstaller, py2exe

I wrote a screenshot program using python and wanted to compile it as `.exe` file. So I tried with both `py2exe` and `pyinstaller`.

My python version is `2.7.14`, 32bit. I use Windows 10. I also use virtual environment in this project.

My code for the screenshot program is like below. I run it by `python screenshot.py` and it take a screenshot of my screen and stored it inside the save directory.

```
from PIL import Image
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import time


time.sleep(3)


save_dir = "C:/Users/ling/Downloads/test/"

def grab():
    im = ImageGrab.grab()
    im.save(save_dir + "screenshot.png")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    grab()
```

## pyinstaller

for `pyinstaller`, I simply install it using `pip install pyinstaller`. The version that was installed -> `3.3.1`. Note that I install this package inside virtual environment.

I compiled the program by running `pyinstaller --onefile screenshot.py`. It generated an executable `screenshot.exe`. When I run the executable, no screenshot was taken.

## py2exe

For installing `py2exe`, since there is some issue regarding installing it on Windows computer running python 2, I followed the tutorial from this [link](https://simpletutorials.com/c/2081/Install+Py2exe+for+Python+2.7+on+Windows)

I create `setup.py` to compiled `screenshot.py` as `screenshot.exe`. Below is the code for `setup.py`

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
      console=[{'script':'screenshot.py'}],
      options = {
            'py2exe': {
                'includes': ['PIL','pyscreenshot','time'],
                'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True
             }
      },
      zipfile = None
)
```

I run it by using `python setup.py py2exe`. It generated a single executable file. When I run this file, the result is same as `pyinstaller`. There is no screenshot taken.

I need help on why does the `screenshot.exe` not working. Am I missing something?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: and when you run the code it works ?

Comment: yes. when i run the code with `python screenshot.py`, it works. I do not know if the execution from `screenshot.exe` is taking a longer time is the problem or there is something that I miss.

Comment: as stated in documentation `grab_to_file: Copy the contents of the screen to a file. Internal function! Use PIL.Image.save() for saving image to file.`. Use Image from PIL. Also, there are libraries that py2exe can't support directly, I rarely work use it, so I can't tell what is happening, but I found something that can be useful here http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/WorkingWithVariousPackagesAndModules and here http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/py2exeAndPIL

Answer (score 1):

Solved it!

Below are the modified code for `screenshot.py`. Run it via `py2exe`.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support
from PIL import Image
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import time

time.sleep(3)


save_dir = "C:/Users/ling/Downloads/test/"

def grab():
    im = ImageGrab.grab()
    im.save(save_dir + "screenshot.png")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    freeze_support()
    p = Process(target=grab)
    p.start()
```

It turned out that I need to include `freeze_support` and `Process` from `multiprocessing`