# After converting to .exe, pyscreenshot doesn't take screenshots

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I've been making a screen-to-text program in Python and I want to convert this to a .exe file. This is because the script needs to run on different systems without Python installed on it.

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import requests
import pyscreenshot

def main():
    currentWattage = 0
    while(True):
        imgGrab = pyscreenshot.grab(bbox=wattageBox)
        img = np.array(imgGrab)
        strRead = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config="--psm 6")
        try:
            wattage = int(strRead)
            if(wattage != currentWattage):
                print("Wattage geupdate, lampen reageren")
                currentWattage = wattage
        except ValueError:
            print("Could not convert " + strRead)
        print(currentWattage)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Start")
    pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
    wattageBox = (150, 400, 240, 430)
    main()
```

If I run it through VS Code, it works fine. I get the result I want. But when I convert it to an .exe file with cx_Freeze, it keeps restarting for some reason and fills up my memory.

I think it has something to do with pyscreenshot, but maybe some of you have experience with pyscreenshot in .exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pyscreenshot uses multiprocessing, and one needs to call the `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` function to freeze a program which uses multiprocessing to produce a Windows executable, see the [multiprocessing documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support).

Try to add the following import to your code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support
```

and to modify its main part as follows:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    freeze_support()
    print("Start")
    pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
    wattageBox = (150, 400, 240, 430)
    Process(target=main).start()
```

This solution has been inspired by [exe generated by py2exe and pyinstaller not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49326762/8516269).

Comment: This really helped a lot, but for some reason it won't go through my main function. It gets a pickle error: can't pickle function main: attribute lookup mian on __main__ failed

Comment: I'm not sure, but have you tried to put these two lines
`pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'`
`wattageBox = (150, 400, 240, 430)`
inside the `main()` function?

Comment: Yeah, it said that it couldn't find those things. So I have them in the main function now. But since then I get that pickle error. It doesn't happen in VS code tho

Comment: I guess the problem is rather with the `pytesseract.tesseract_cmd` statement. Try to pass `pytesseract` as a parameter to `main` using `def main(pytesseract):` and `Process(target=main, args=(pytesseract, )).start()` and leave the `pytesseract.tesseract_cmd` statement before this `Process` call. Move the `wattageBox` definition into the `main(pytesseract)` function, this should not be a problem (or pass it as a parameter as well if you need so).

Comment: so i tried this, and it works initially - but when i put the function into another file, and then call it into the main function where the `freeze_suppport()` lies, it doenst work